# I want to create a category page. I am using Gatsby.js, GraphQL and Strapi

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I want to create a category page. I am using Gatsby.js, GraphQL and Strapi.
Probably filter is not working.
But I don't know how to solve it.

{strapiCategory.slug}.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";
import PostList from "../../components/PostList";
import *as styles from "./{MicrocmsCategory.slug}.module.css";
const CategoryPage = (props) => {
  const categories = props.data.strapiCategory;
  const posts = props.data.allStrapiPost.nodes;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{categories.name}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={categories.name} />
      </Helmet>
     <p className={styles.categoryName}> {categories.name}</p>
      <PostList posts={posts} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const query = graphql`
query ($slug: String!){
  strapiCategory (slug: { eq: $slug }){
    name
    slug
    
  }
    allStrapiPost(filter:{categories:{slug:{ eq: $slug }}}){
      nodes {
        slug
        title
        content
        thumbnail
        published_at(formatString: "YYYY.MM.DD hh:mm")
        categories {
          slug
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default CategoryPage;
```

error code

> ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
>
> Generating development JavaScript bundle failed
>
> /Users/t/WebDevelopment/xxxxxx/src/pages/categories/{xxxx.slug}.js
> 29:39  error  Field "slug" is not defined by type
> "StrapiPostCategoriesFilterListInput"  graphql/template-strings
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
>
> failed Re-building development bundle - 0.177s ERROR in
> /Users/t/WebDevelopment/xxxx/src/pages/categories/{xxxxxx.slug}.js
> 29:39  error  Field "slug" is not defined by type
> "StrapiPostCategoriesFilterListInput"

The link is working fine.

It will be displayed.

```
  const categories = props.data.strapiCategory;
        <title>{categories.name}</title>.
```

This will not be displayed.

```
const posts = props.data.allStrapiPost.nodes;
 <PostList posts={posts} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Field "slug" is not defined by type
> "StrapiPostCategoriesFilterListInput" graphql/template-strings

It's quite self-explanatory. In your case, `slug` is under `categories` (collection/nested route in [FileSystem API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/#collection-routes)).

Your `{xxxxx.slug}.js` should become:

```
{xxxxx.categories.slug}.js
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to look like {Strapi.categories}.js.
However, when I click on a category, I get a 404 page.

I think it's probably a problem with the filter.
But I have no solution.
I will be happy if you can continue to support me.

Comment: I named the file the same as the query.
{strapiCategory.slug}.js

Then I was able to display the category page.
However, Post did not show up.

I wrote the following code in PostCell, a component for creating content.
I wrote the following code.
    <Link to={`/categories/${category.slug}` } className={styles.link}>

Comment: So, the page now is being created but the link isn't working?

Comment: The link is working fine.
I have added the text.

Comment: But this is a completely new (old) issue. Gatsby always queries for the `id` and you are using the `slug` (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/). You can't do this query using filesystem route API. You should use the traditional `gatsby-node.js`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using where instead of filter in graphql

```
allStrapiPost(where:{categories:{slug:{ eq: $slug }}}){
```